# Clear Touch Events Queue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, queue, touch-event

I have an activity that usually lags a second or two before actually displaying the main content. During this very brief lag period, if someone taps the screen rapidly, I suspect, that the touch events get queued up and are all dispatched at the same time when the activity is eventually shown. This problem is causing a `View` I have on the activity to crash because it receives a burst of those touch events instantaneously and doesn't have time to process them.

I've been able to find a way to detect the moment after the start-up lag and want to ask if anyone knows how to clear the touch events queue?

Comment: you could ignore the touches in the view until that moment after the start-up. in that particular moment you can set a flag in the view so future touch inputs will be handled normally again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem with that is that the touch events queue is still built up with touch events that all get dispatched instantaneously. If I "unlock" the `View` when the activity is ready those touch events will still burst onto that `View`.

Comment: what if you put the work it takes to load the activity in another thread so the main thread (i.e. the touches) don't pile up and can be handled instantly?